# installation using pip on conda env taking very long time

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am trying to install the below requirements contained in a file requirements.txt in a conda environment:

```
amazon-braket-pennylane-plugin==1.1.0.post1
cvxopt==1.2.6
cvxpy==1.1.11
dill==0.3.3
ipywidgets==7.6.3
jupyter==1.0.0
jupytext==1.10.2
matplotlib==3.3.4
Mosek==9.2.40
notebook==6.2.0
numpy==1.19.5
pandas==1.2.2
pytest==6.2.2
scikit-learn==0.24.1
scipy==1.6.0
seaborn==0.11.1
sklearn==0.0
sympy==1.7.1
tqdm==4.57.0
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
pennylane==0.16.0
pennylane-cirq==0.14.0
keras==2.4.3
tensorflow==2.4.1
rsmf==0.2
```

The command I using to install is :

```
pip install -r src/requirements.txt --upgrade
```

[Github link](https://github.com/thubregtsen/qhack)

But this installation is not complete and is continuing many hours as shown below. I am not sure why it is taking so long and what should I do to install the software correctly?

```
    Downloading protobuf-3.20.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.0/1.0 MB 94.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0
  Downloading google_api_core-1.34.0-py3-none-any.whl (120 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 120.2/120.2 kB 48.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyquil>=3.2.0
  Downloading pyquil-3.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.6/221.6 kB 47.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting psutil
  Downloading psutil-5.9.4-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (280 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 280.2/280.2 kB 74.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting debugpy>=1.6.5
  Downloading debugpy-1.6.6-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.1/3.1 MB 83.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting comm>=0.1.1
  Downloading comm-0.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
Collecting matplotlib-inline>=0.1
  Downloading matplotlib_inline-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl (9.4 kB)
Collecting pygments>=2.4.0
  Downloading Pygments-2.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.1/1.1 MB 93.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting stack-data
  Downloading stack_data-0.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit!=3.0.37,<3.1.0,>=3.0.30
  Downloading prompt_toolkit-3.0.38-py3-none-any.whl (385 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 385.8/385.8 kB 84.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting backcall
  Downloading backcall-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pexpect>4.3
  Using cached pexpect-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting decorator
  Downloading decorator-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
Collecting pickleshare
  Using cached pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
Collecting jedi>=0.16
  Downloading jedi-0.18.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.6/1.6 MB 111.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting importlib-metadata>=4.8.3
  Downloading importlib_metadata-6.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting platformdirs>=2.5
  Downloading platformdirs-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting mdit-py-plugins~=0.2.1
  Downloading mdit_py_plugins-0.2.8-py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 41.0/41.0 kB 16.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting attrs>=19.2.0
  Downloading attrs-20.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 49.3/49.3 kB 18.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting jsonschema>=2.6
  Downloading jsonschema-4.17.3-py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 90.4/90.4 kB 31.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting fastjsonschema
  Downloading fastjsonschema-2.16.3-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting qdldl
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.5.post3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.0/1.0 MB 95.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorboard-data-server<0.8.0,>=0.7.0
  Downloading tensorboard_data_server-0.7.0-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (6.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6.6/6.6 MB 97.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorboard~=2.4
  Downloading tensorboard-2.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (6.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6.0/6.0 MB 98.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting google-auth<3,>=1.6.3
  Downloading google_auth-2.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 178.1/178.1 kB 66.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8
  Downloading Markdown-3.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 93.9/93.9 kB 39.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorboard-data-server<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
  Using cached tensorboard_data_server-0.6.1-py3-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (4.9 MB)
Collecting werkzeug>=1.0.1
  Downloading Werkzeug-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (233 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 233.6/233.6 kB 78.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0
  Using cached tensorboard_plugin_wit-1.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (781 kB)
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting ptyprocess
  Using cached ptyprocess-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting argon2-cffi-bindings
  Downloading argon2_cffi_bindings-21.2.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (86 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 86.2/86.2 kB 24.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting future>=0.15.2
  Downloading future-0.18.3.tar.gz (840 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 840.9/840.9 kB 104.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (25 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab-pygments
  Downloading jupyterlab_pygments-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting nbclient>=0.5.0
  Downloading nbclient-0.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 72.0/72.0 kB 26.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tinycss2
  Downloading tinycss2-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (132 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 132.2/132.2 kB 51.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting defusedxml
  Downloading defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting bleach
  Downloading bleach-6.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 162.5/162.5 kB 55.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting mistune<3,>=2.0.3
  Downloading mistune-2.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1
  Downloading pandocfilters-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.7 kB)
Collecting qtpy>=2.0.1
  Downloading QtPy-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 84.9/84.9 kB 35.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting antlr4-python3-runtime==4.9.2
  Downloading antlr4-python3-runtime-4.9.2.tar.gz (117 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 117.2/117.2 kB 40.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pydantic<2.0,>=1.9
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.7-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 101.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting s3transfer<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
  Downloading s3transfer-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 79.6/79.6 kB 35.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1
  Downloading jmespath-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting botocore<1.30.0,>=1.29.102
  Downloading botocore-1.29.102-py3-none-any.whl (10.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.6/10.6 MB 94.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4
  Downloading rsa-4.9-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Downloading pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 155.3/155.3 kB 53.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0
  Downloading cachetools-5.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0
  Using cached requests_oauthlib-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting zipp>=0.5
  Downloading zipp-3.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Collecting parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0
  Downloading parso-0.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 100.8/100.8 kB 39.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,>=0.14.0
  Downloading pyrsistent-0.19.3-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 57.5/57.5 kB 21.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting importlib-resources>=1.4.0
  Downloading importlib_resources-5.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting pkgutil-resolve-name>=1.3.10
  Downloading pkgutil_resolve_name-1.3.10-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
Collecting mdit-py-plugins~=0.2.1
  Downloading mdit_py_plugins-0.2.7-py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 41.0/41.0 kB 13.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading mdit_py_plugins-0.2.6-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting mypy-extensions>=0.2.0
  Downloading mypy_extensions-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
Collecting wcwidth
  Downloading wcwidth-0.2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2
  Downloading charset_normalizer-3.1.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (195 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 195.9/195.9 kB 67.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/m992c693/anaconda3/envs/qhack_paper/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests~=2.18->cirq-aqt==1.1.0->cirq>=0.9->pennylane-cirq==0.14.0->-r src/requirements.txt (line 22)) (2022.12.7)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.5/61.5 kB 24.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 140.9/140.9 kB 55.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting cffi>=1.0.1
  Downloading cffi-1.15.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (442 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 442.7/442.7 kB 93.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting soupsieve>1.2
  Downloading soupsieve-2.4-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting webencodings
  Downloading webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pure-eval
  Downloading pure_eval-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting asttokens>=2.1.0
  Downloading asttokens-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting executing>=1.2.0
  Downloading executing-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting pycparser
  Using cached pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
Collecting googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.56.2
  Downloading googleapis_common_protos-1.59.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (223 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 223.6/223.6 kB 77.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0
  Downloading google_api_core-1.33.2-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 115.5/115.5 kB 47.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading google_api_core-1.33.1-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 115.5/115.5 kB 35.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading google_api_core-1.33.0-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 115.2/115.2 kB 40.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading google_api_core-1.32.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 93.6/93.6 kB 34.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting google-auth<3,>=1.6.3
  Downloading google_auth-1.35.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (152 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 152.9/152.9 kB 55.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0
  Downloading cachetools-4.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6
  Downloading pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 77.1/77.1 kB 32.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pydantic<2.0,>=1.9
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.6-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 99.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 99.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 101.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (13.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.6/13.6 MB 74.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (13.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.5/13.5 MB 93.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (13.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.5/13.5 MB 92.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pydantic-1.9.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 12.8/12.8 MB 91.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyquil>=3.2.0
  Downloading pyquil-3.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.5/221.5 kB 73.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pyquil-3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.4/221.4 kB 49.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pyquil-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.4/221.4 kB 78.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting qcs-api-client<0.22.0,>=0.20.13
  Downloading qcs_api_client-0.21.3-py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 147.4/147.4 kB 36.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyquil>=3.2.0
  Downloading pyquil-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.3/221.3 kB 48.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pyquil-3.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.0/221.0 kB 77.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pyquil-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.0/221.0 kB 48.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pydantic to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyasn1-modules to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Downloading pyasn1_modules-0.2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (131 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 131.4/131.4 kB 45.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of proto-plus to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting proto-plus>=1.20.0
  Downloading proto_plus-1.22.1-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 47.9/47.9 kB 20.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pkgutil-resolve-name to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of parso to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0
  Downloading parso-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 94.0/94.0 kB 26.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of mypy-extensions to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting mypy-extensions>=0.2.0
  Downloading mypy_extensions-0.4.4.tar.gz (4.2 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jmespath to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1
  Downloading jmespath-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of importlib-resources to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting importlib-resources>=1.4.0
  Downloading importlib_resources-5.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of idna to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.2/61.2 kB 23.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of cachetools to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0
  Downloading cachetools-4.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of google-auth to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting google-auth<3,>=1.6.3
  Downloading google_auth-1.34.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (152 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 152.9/152.9 kB 38.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of google-api-core[grpc] to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of executing to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of duet to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of charset-normalizer to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2
  Downloading charset_normalizer-3.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (195 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 195.4/195.4 kB 59.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of cffi to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting cffi>=1.0.1
  Downloading cffi-1.15.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (446 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 446.7/446.7 kB 87.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of certifi to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Downloading certifi-2022.12.7-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 155.3/155.3 kB 50.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0
  Downloading cachetools-5.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of botocore to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of asttokens to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting asttokens>=2.1.0
  Downloading asttokens-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of tinycss2 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting tinycss2
  Downloading tinycss2-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of stack-data to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting stack-data
  Downloading stack_data-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of qdldl to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting qdldl
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.5.post2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.0/1.0 MB 108.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.5.post0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.0/1.0 MB 90.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (921 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 921.4/921.4 kB 86.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (852 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 852.4/852.4 kB 90.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (852 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 852.3/852.3 kB 88.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (847 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 847.4/847.4 kB 76.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (828 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 828.7/828.7 kB 81.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of qdldl to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Downloading qdldl-0.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (549 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 549.2/549.2 kB 75.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of psutil to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting psutil
  Downloading psutil-5.9.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (295 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 295.6/295.6 kB 88.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. See https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/backtracking for guidance. If you want to abort this run, press Ctrl + C.
```

Comment: The upstream code provider needs to be more specific with rules.  `psutil` and others have MULTIPLE versions so it has to determine which version to *actually* use.  That's the chaotic issue.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasWard for response. Please suggest changes in requirements.txt file?

Comment: Looking deeper this might not be something you can resolve easily, `pip` is trying to ID which version of the library works with the dependencies needed for other modules defined in requirements.txt.  I can't give you any guidance to fix it.